# Window Remote Desktop pinching USB?

Tags: usb, virtualbox, remote-desktop

I have Virtualbox (6.1.16) running a Ubuntu VM from a USB stick on a Windows 10 machine. I am also using Remote Desktop on that Windows 10 machine to view and work on a separate Windows 10 machine.

I am experiencing USB issues where the Virtualbox gives an error, the virtual machine stops and the USB stick is no longer mounted on the Windows 10 machine (and isn't on the remote Win10 either).

I don't have USB resource sharing selected for Remote Desktop. The issue takes a few minutes to manifest. I am using some USB devices in VirtualBox. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a hardware problem replacing the drive should be the first thing you try

Comment: I tried a new drive with the same result. Doing some more Googling highlighted turning of power settings under windows associated with USB.